# Is there anyway I can generate an infinite list of four strings in python

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, infinite

I have a list of four colors which I want to generate an infinite list such that when I enter a random index, it will show me the color found in that position

Comment: for storing infinite amount of data we need infinite amount of storage.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
number = int(input('write your index here:'))
color = ['b', 'k', 'g', 'y']
chosen_color = color[number%len(color)]
print(chosen_color)
```

Output:

```
write your index here: 98435164
b
```